# CSS conditional selector either this or that

Tags: css, css-selectors

currently i have something like this

```
$("#foo").click(function () {callMe();});
$("#bar").click(function () {callMe();});
```

foo and bar do the same thing. Is there a way for me to define a selector saying either if foo id or bar id is called then trigger the click event ? I tried this but it did not work

```
 $("#foo","#bar").click(function () {callMe();});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could give them a class and then  check the id of the target element:

```js
$('').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.currentTarget.id === 'foo') {
    console.log('foo clicked');
  } else {
    console.log('bar clicked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click" id="foo">foo</div>
<div class="click" id="bar">bar</div>
```

Or if I'm misunderstanding the question and you just want to select both elements using their ids, you can just use

```
$('#foo,#bar').on('click', function() {});
```

note the comma is in the quotes, not separate quotes

Answer (score 0):

The syntax and the code looks fine, I think you haven't imported jQuery properly.

I tried the same, and it works fine. Have a look at the code below.

```js
function callMe () {
alert("callMe function called!");
} 

$("#foo, #bar").click(function () {callMe();});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="foo"> foo </button> 
<button id="bar"> bar </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", callMe);

function callMe(e) {
  let id = e.target.id
  console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button id="foo">Foo</button>
  <br> <br>
  <button id="bar">bar</button>
</div>
```